# Width attribute of html tag do not work well because of contents

Tags: html, css, width

I have a table like below

```
<table width="50px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I set `width="50px"`, width of table is bigger than 50px unless I reduce  size of font.

I want to make width of table same with just what I set in attribute(`width="50px"`).

Is there any way to reduce size of font automatically to fit table's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `style="table-layout: fixed;"` to the table to constrain the proportions.

```html
<table width="50px" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also you're creating columns there not rows... you're not going to be able to add any readable text to those!

Rows should be seperated by `<tr>'s`